# Alignment of chemical equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, chemistry

I would like to align some chemical reactions in my document.
This is an example of what I did:

```
\begin{equation}
\nuclide[14][7]{N} + n \to \nuclide[14][6]{C} + p
\end{equation}

<Some text>

\begin{align*}
 &\nuclide[14][7]{N} + n \to \nuclide[11][5]{B} + \nuclide[4][2]{H}\\%
 &\nuclide[14][7]{N} + n \to \nuclide[12][6]{C} + \nuclide[3][1]{H}\\%

\end{align*}
```

I would like to align the first equation with the next two. How can I do?

Comment: Have you tried one of amsmath’s environments, say `align`?

Comment: @FordPrefect: What was the sense of your change to Torbjorn’s edit in http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/89108/10? The way he made the indentation is exactly, how the syntax highlighting/markup system called Markdown expects it for showing code blocks. With your edit there came additional (useless) indentation.

Comment: Re your edit: How long is `<Some text>`? For short text, use `\intertext{<some text>}` (or `\shortintertext` from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) inside (!) one (!) `align` environment (or its kind). For long text (which indicates your paragraphs = empty lines in source) I’d advise against it. Though you could do it by some trickery with `\hphantom` and `\mathllap` (`mathtools` required). [cont …]

Comment: [… cont] Can you extend your question: what should aligned to what? Maybe you are more interested in the `fleqn` option (see [`amsmath` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf), p. 3).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to use a chemistry package like [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) (together with the already proposed [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) instead of `tensor`? `mhchem`'s `\ce` macro is defined especially for use in alignment environments like `{align}`.
For text between aligned equations one can use `amsmath`'s `\intertext{}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \ce{^{14}_7N + n &-> ^{11}_5B  + ^4_2H}
 \intertext{Some text in between that is not aligned or anything.}
 \ce{
   ^{14}_7N + n &-> ^{12}_6C  + ^3_1H \\
   ^{16}_8O + n &-> ^{10}_4Be + ^7_4Be
 }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** In order to get the first equation numbered but not the second and third you have basically two options:

1. Use `{align}` (without the star!) and suppress the numbers of the second and third  equation via `\notag` or `\nonumber`.
2. Use `{align*}` and add the number for the first manually by saying `\tag{\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation}`

Personally I prefer the first variant. BTW: if you haven't read it yet you might want to have a look at “[Math Mode](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode)” by Herbert Voß.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \ce{^{14}_7N + n &-> ^{11}_5B  + ^4_2H}
 \intertext{Some text in between that is not aligned or anything.}
 \ce{
   ^{14}_7N + n &-> ^{12}_6C  + ^3_1H \nonumber \\
   ^{16}_8O + n &-> ^{10}_4Be + ^7_4Be \notag
 }
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
 \ce{
   ^{14}_7N + n &-> ^{11}_5B  + ^4_2H \tag{\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation}
}
 \intertext{Some text in between that is not aligned or anything.}
 \ce{
   ^{14}_7N + n &-> ^{12}_6C  + ^3_1H \\
   ^{16}_8O + n &-> ^{10}_4Be + ^7_4Be 
 }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try the `align*` environment, provided by `amsmath` package. To change the position of the aligment, change the `&` symbol.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   &\nuclide[14][7]{N} + n \to \nuclide[11][5]{B}  + \nuclide[4][2]{H}\\
   &\nuclide[14][7]{N} + n \to \nuclide[12][6]{C}  + \nuclide[3][1]{H}\\
   &\nuclide[16][8]{O} + n \to \nuclide[10][4]{Be} + \nuclide[7][4]{Be}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The environment align works very well. But how do I do if between equations I have some text (that I would like rest "normal")?

Comment: @FordPrefect try `\intertext{<text>}`. Have you read [Math Mode](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode), yet?

Comment: @FordPrefect, text between equations should be written on a normal line? Or centered? Please, exemplify it.

Comment: @Sigur I edited my question. Sorry for the bad explanations...